# set alphanumeric input with maxlength

Tags: html

```
<input class='inpuname' type='text' maxlength=5>
```

`maxlength` works

Now, I want the all of five characters to be alphanumeric

```
<input class='inpuname' type='text' pattern='[A-Za-z0-9]{5}' maxlength=5>
```

either `maxlength` nor `pattern` doesn't work. Any characters and any number of characters are allowed !

Comment: for me it works all fine. Please create a code snippet / jsfiddle that reproduces the problem

Comment: @smnbbrv, here - `https://jsfiddle.net/5aw7tz0d/`

Comment: @puerto https://jsfiddle.net/5aw7tz0d/1/ works for me on chrome

Comment: @puerto what exactly as you understand does not work? How should it work in your opinion?

Comment: @smnbbrv, I need max 5 charcters and only alphanumeric. On js fiddle I can write all charachters and any number of them.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="demo">
number:
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]{5}"
   maxlength=5
   title="5 digit number">

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This works. Try submitting the form with valid and invalid data

Comment: but my input is `text` type.

Comment: and `</input>` is invalid in HTML

Comment: Check the answer. Try submitting the form